# Download pdf files with the label name shown in webpage

Tags: php, file, web-scraping, web-crawler

My problem is kind off tricky and i have currently no solution or code to show.
I have some more than 500 pdf files listed on my local webpage. listed like below.

```
<a href="123.pdf">Car List</a>
<a href="456.pdf">Bike List</a>
<a href="789.pdf">Ship List</a>
```

Now as usual in webpage they will show links like

Car List

Bike List

Ship List

Now I want to **download all the pdf files with the label name**. I want the file to be downloaded like **Car List.pdf** not like **123.pdf**. Now files are like more than 500, so, its not possible to do manually.

My webpages are in php. Any idea or script to do that ?

Comment: It would probably be useful to know which webserver, on which platform, you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a header to rename the output. For instance like this:

```
<?php

$InputName = $_GET['Input'];
$outputName = $_GET['Output'];

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$outputName.'"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

readfile('<...path to pdf files...>'.$InputName);
```

You can then use these types of links:

```
<a href="openPdf.php?Input=123.pdf&Output=Car%20List.pdf">Car List</a>
```

Note that `Content-Disposition: inline;` will open the file in your browser, whereas `Content-Disposition: attachment;` will act as a download.

If you want your links to only contain the "real" file names you would probably have to do something with the configuration your web server.

Comment: will it download all the files automatically.. or i have to click on save or whatever save button all the 500 files ?

Comment: @Koushik Ah, I missed that in your question, you want to download all the files automatically. That could be done with a bit of JavaScript. See for instance: [How trigger file downloads with JavaScript](https://www.stefanjudis.com/snippets/how-trigger-file-downloads-with-javascript/). You can write the 500 downloads in a PHP script that would generate the correct JavaScript code.

Comment: Keep in mind that 500 files is a lot. You can create a script like this for yourself, but don't let other, innocent, people use it. They won't know what hit them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write download.php to output the pdf with the name you want.

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// $_GET['FileName'] is the "Cat List.pdf"
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $_GET['FileName'] . '.pdf"');

// $_GET['File'] is the "123.pdf"
readfile($_GET['File']);
?>
```

2. Replace all `<a href="123.pdf">Car List</a>` by `<a href="download.php?File=123.pdf&FileName=Car%20List>Car List</a>` with text replace function by IDE

Comment: again i have to click or save button in dialogue box.. for all 500 files..

Comment: Is it possible to rename and download them via FTP?
If so, you can archive this by rename the files....

For Linux:
At the webpages, change every line to format like `mv 123.pdf 'Cat List.pdf'`.
Then copy all the lines and run them in terminal

For Windows:
At the webpages, change every line to format like `ren "123.pdf" "Cat List.pdf"`.
Then copy all the lines and run them in cmd